# Using Asp.net MVC web.api why should I redirect rather than just call other functions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a put and post method in controller that when they work, they would normally redirect to the get method. But I noticed that using the redirect process in MVC is slower than just returning the call of the get method.

Sample from MS code:

```
return RedirectToRoute("someRoute", routeVarWithId);
```

What I found that takes less time:

```
return Get(Id);
```

Since my put, post, and get, all return IHttpActonResult, I don't see why I should use the redirect if the call is within my one controller, and the security rights are the same.

Am I missing anything obvious here?

Comment: Because thats the HTTP standard? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: Here is another document specific to web api. http://micheltriana.com/2013/09/30/http-verbs-in-a-rest-web-api/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I noticed that using the redirect process in MVC is slower than just returning the call of the get method.

Of course it is; there are now two requests.

> Am I missing anything obvious here?

Imagine I submit a form as a `POST` request to order a new computer from your website. Instead of returning a redirect to my order page, it just renders it out. Then my cat jumps on the keyboard and hits `CTRL+R` (refresh). What happens? My browser resubmits the last request, which was the `POST`. Now I've ordered two computers!

Instead, after successfully processing the `POST` request, you should return a redirect to the order page, which my browser will fetch with a `GET`. Now I can refresh to my heart's content and nothing bad will ever happen.

This also gives the user the ability to bookmark the page or email it to my wife. You can't email links that are `POST` requests.

For some light reading on the topic, refer to the [HTTP/1.1 standard](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), specifically section 9.5 and following:

> If a resource has been created on the origin server, the response
>   SHOULD be 201 (Created) and contain an entity which describes the
>   status of the request and refers to the new resource, and a Location
>   header (see section 14.30).

So when a `POST` creates a new resource, like an Order, it should return a `201 Created` redirect to the URL where the new resource (i.e. the order) can be retrieved.

Comment: So I should use the redirect when "bad stuff" can happen from multiple refreshes, where as If I don't care, then I can call direct. *** Since these are web API calls, I have tried testing the refresh issue, and I don't seem to have an issue where I get double posts.

Comment: Yes, If your doing an API, the pattern is slightly less relevant. But it's a common enough pattern for REST services that your API users will expect. But if you're the only client, you can do what we've makes things easiest for you.

Comment: I might add that from a philosophical standpoint, creating a resource and viewing the details of a resource are two different things and are thus two different HTTP verbs in separate requests.

Comment: I am at the point where I am trying to trim every milisecond off of my application. Since I have already replaced all of my SQL calls with the most optimized stored procedures (and functions,) indexes are solid, and have completed all of my other code reduction, I am down to this and removing Ioc Di. Since I refuse to remove Ioc Di, preserve flexibility and unit testing, I am down to this. It isn't even that the code is running slow, but I always want to challenge myself to have the fastest code possible.